# Scaling user image uploads on Heroku with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, carrierwave, scaling

I have a Rails app on Heroku that seems to be having trouble scaling the way I want it to. In the app, a user can upload multiple nested images to an invoice.  Based on my research, it seems that this ties up a Heroku web dyno (I'm running 3) until it's done uploading.  I've looked into Carrierwave Direct so that a web dyno isn't used but it doesn't seem that this is compatible with a nested model.  Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't upload images to Heroku.  It will lock your entire web server.  Instead, use a jQuery library (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to upload directly to Amazon S3 from the client side.